# Open a page over another page bootstrap jQuery

Tags: jquery, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I'm using spring and jsp for my web-app.

I'm trying to create a component like this:

[image]

When I click on a button inside the "master" page, I want open a second page over the first one.

Is there a component using bootstrap or jQuery to do this?

Otherwise how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What about using `modal`? Example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h)

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @A modal is opened over the entire page, I want open it like a slide from right to left

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you require to open a popup window
you can easily do this by installing any free popup overlay jquery pluging like- ( http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Responsive-Accessible-jQuery-Modal-Plugin-Popup-Overlay.html )
install only if you want to create many popup overlay items